# Android Firebase : retrieve All data in ArrayList and randomly select string from that ArrayList

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app with Firebase in which user can share quotes. Data is inserted successfully and it looks like this in database after each value inserted. 
please see this image for database values:

[image: please see this image for database values]

and I want to fetch all the data in an ArrayList. and `onclick` of refresh button the TextView should be updated to new value that will be randomly selected from ArrayList. I have tried something like this. but its not working. it showing nullpointerexception.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater paramLayoutInflater, ViewGroup paramViewGroup, Bundle paramBundle) {
    this.localView = paramLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenthome, paramViewGroup, false);
    story = (TextView) localView.findViewById(R.id.story_text);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) localView.findViewById(R.id.rlLayout);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) localView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);
    imgRefresh = (ImageView) localView.findViewById(R.id.refreshStory);


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("stories");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            storiesary = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                storiesary.add(childSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    imgRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setStory();
        }
    });

    return localView;

}

public void setStory()
{
    int arraysize = storiesary.size();
    final int arrayposition1 = (new Random()).nextInt(arraysize);
    story.setText(storiesary.get(arrayposition1));
}
```

Comment: post error log here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         storiesary = new ArrayList<String>();
         for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               HashMap map =(HashMap) childSnapshot.getValue();
               if(map!=null) {
                   storiesary.add(map.get("storytext"));
               }
               //or 
              String name = (String) childSnapshot.child("storytext").getValue();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         Log.d(TAG,"Error");
      }
   });
```